# Take a screenshot in mplayer2 and upload it to an image sharing site in one keypress

Tags: bash, mplayer

I have a bash script that uploads screenshots to imgur. I want mplayer to take a screenshot, and then upload it with the bash script, and all that in a single keypress. Is there a way to queue taking a screenshot and then running a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Basically it is a bash script that emulates a keypress in `mplayer` window, and then proceeds to sending the screenshot to imgur. All the scripting is done outside `mplayer`, so you can just use your DE/WM/xbindkeys to bind it to any key. Here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
# press s to take a screenshot; vf=screenshot must be added to ~/.mplayer/confing
xdotool search --class mplayer2 key s 

# So there's enough time for a screenshot to be written to a file.
sleep 0.3

cd /proc/`pidof mplayer`/cwd
imgur shot*.png
rm shot*.png
```

I'm using [this script](https://github.com/c00kiemon5ter/scripts/blob/master/imgur) as the `imgur` command. `mplayer` must be already running for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

So far as I know, this is not possible in exactly the way you're thinking. You can take a screenshot in mplayer/mplayer2 with the shortcut `s`, but then having the player signal a bash script to upload the taken image will be very difficult. Though, it appears that [mpv](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv), a fork of mplayer and MPlayer2, may make this much simpler by allowing a user to [bind multiple commands](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/DOCS/man/en/input.rst) (including external ones).

There are a couple ways around this:

1. Run a bash script in the background that watches a particular directory (you'll need to have your player put its screenshots in this directory—the default is `$PWD` of the player instance) which will detect newly added pictures and call the upload script on them.
2. Don't try and have your player handle this kind of task, instead bind a key for your Window Manager or Desktop Environment. The key you bind would call an external tool (e.g., [scrot](http://freecode.com/projects/scrot)) and then call the upload script on the resulting image.
3. Switch to mpv, and redefine the `s` command in `input.conf` to take a screenshot and then call the upload script on it.

`1` has a couple of obvious problems. First, it will waste a ton of resources to have a bash script like this constantly watching a folder. And, second, it will be somewhat difficult (though not impossible) to get the bash script to recognize images it has already uploaded and not repeat the task.

`2` has several advantages. First, you're not trying to do scripting inside your media player (generally an odd idea). Second, it's far more generalizable—you can use the same function anywhere in your environment, not just your player.

`3`'s advantage is that it remains simple and actually accomplishes exactly what you want. The negative is that you would need to switch media players.

---

Without knowing what WM/DE you use, giving you a specific process to follow is not possible, but I would strongly recommend following option `2` unless you feel okay trying out mpv. If you are willing to take a look at a different tool, mpv is a wonderful fork.